# Artifactory: How to keep N versions of a Release (not snapshot)?

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way in Artifactory to only keep N versions of a RELEASED artifact?

Nexus has a scheduled task that can be configured to do this, but I can't find one in Artifactory. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place?

The reason I ask is that we have an maven repo that doubles as yum repo, and with continuous builds going on, we are constantly uploading rpms (which are "release" artifacts, not "snapshot" artifacts), so they quickly eat up space.

Do I have to write my own script to clean up released artifacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you look for (a scheduled task that can perform any action, inc. cleanup) is user plugins in general, and [scheduled jobs](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Jobs) in particular.

Using [Public API](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html) (specially, `repositories` and/or `searches` objects) you can easily delete artifacts based on you custom logic.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing a python script to clean up my yum artifacts by hitting api/storage/myrepo/rpms?list&deep=1&listFolders=1

Comment: I think user plugin is a better option. It runs on the server side and you don't need another machine to keep the scheduler running.

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch, I'll read up on user plugins to see how I can do this.